# How to create a Facebook-like sticky bar

Tags: jquery

Here check this video to see what I really mean [(Video)](https://youtu.be/dDJdhzjmimw)

Now you will notice the left bar when I scroll. When I scroll to the bottom of the bar, the bar becomes sticky, and no matter how far I scrolled, immediately I scroll up the bar scrolls up too until it reaches the top of the bar again.

So far, I did come up with a sticky bar, but I want if I scroll the bar scrolls up too until it reaches the top just like the facebook style.

This is my code so far

```
function stickDown($el, margin, position){

    var elPos = $el.offset().top + $el.height() + margin;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var winS = $(window).scrollTop();
        var winH = $(window).height();

        if(winS + winH > elPos)
            $el.attr('style', 'position:fixed;bottom:'+margin+'px;top:auto;');
        else
            $el.attr('style', 'position:'+position+';');        
    })

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    stickDown($('div#bar'), 10, 'relative');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Here is my new code

```
var winScrTop = 0,
oldScrTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    winScrTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    winH = $(this).height();
    $bar = $('div#bar');
    barTop = $bar.offset().top;
    barH = $bar.height();
    margin = 10;
    scrH = winScrTop + winH;
    topMar = barTop - winScrTop;
    allbar = barTop + barH + margin;
    if(winScrTop > oldScrTop){
        if(scrH > allbar && topMar < 100){
            $bar.css({
                position:'fixed',
                top: topMar+'px'
            })
        } else {
            $bar.css({
                position:'absolute',
                top: barTop+'px'
            })
        }
    } else {
        if(scrH > allbar){
            nin = winScrTop - barTop;
            $bar.css({
                position:'absolute',
                top: nin+'px'
            })
        }
        if(topMar > 99){
            $bar.css({
                position:'fixed',
                top: '100px'
            })
        }
    }
    oldScrTop = winScrTop;
})
```